# performLongClick does not work in an activity android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an auto-click application for android. By designing a floating window, the location of the desired place for clicking is found but performLongClick function does not work in the activity.

```
if (count == 0) {
            count = count +1;
            startrobot.setText("اجرای ربات");
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingView.class));
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ACTION_DOWN AT COORDS "+"X: "+FloatingView.X+" Y: "+FloatingView.Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            v.performLongClick(FloatingView.X,FloatingView.Y);

        }
```

performLongClick does not work in both activity's View and webview.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an error ? Nothing is happening? Tell us more.

Comment: there is no error. nothing is happening. I want to do a programmatic click in the activity

Comment: Is the toast showing ?

Comment: yes. coordinates are shown in the Toast